# Async.js: Is a variable created in a waterfall task available in another task?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I am freshly discovering Async.js and I wondered what was the behavior of `async.waterfall` when a document is found by a *database query*, and how to use it through different tasks.

I have this piece of code :

```
var _arg1;
var _arg2;
async.waterfall([
    function (callback) { // First "dummy" callback
      callback(null, _arg1, _arg2);
    },
    function (arg1, arg2, callback) {
      foo1(arg1, arg2, callback); // Built-in function, for example a database query returning a document
    },
    function (arg3, callback) {
      foo2(arg3, callback); // arg3 is the document found by the query
    },
    function (callback) {
      foo3(arg3, callback); // Here I would like to use `arg3` again
    }], 
    function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
);
```

Is it possible to use `arg1` in my second task, without storing the variables every time ?

I think I could do something like this, but I'm sure it is not the best way to do it :

```
var _arg1;
var _arg2;
var _arg3;
async.waterfall([
    function (callback) { // First "dummy" callback
      callback(null, _arg1, _arg2);
    },
    function (arg1, arg2, callback) {
      foo1(arg1, arg2, callback); // Built-in function, for example a database query returning a document
    },
    function (arg3, callback) {
      _arg3 = arg3
      foo2(arg3, callback); // arg3 is the document found by the query
    },
    function (callback) {
      foo3(_arg3, callback); // Make use gain of `_arg3` ?
    }], 
    function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
);
```

What is the best way to manipulate different variables created in tasks?

Comment: That looks so nasty. Everything points to asynchronicity in Javascript being managed through the [use of `Promise`](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises). If you want code that looks at least slightly fresh in a couple of years time, then Promises are the way forward. They've even made (really nice) changes to the language itself that rely on the Promise API. I wouldn't bother too much with this callback-y code. It looks old already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each waterfall function has his own scope, so it's not possible to share variables. I can only think this two options:

- Declare outside the waterfall the variables (the one you did)
- Pass the variables to the next function using the callbacks

Second one would be something like this:

```
var _arg1;
var _arg2;
async.waterfall([
    function (callback) { // First "dummy" callback
      callback(null, _arg1, _arg2);
    },
    function (arg1, arg2, callback) {
      foo1(arg1, arg2, callback); // Built-in function, for example a database query returning a document
    },
    function (arg3, callback) {
      foo2(arg3, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          callback(err);
        }
        callback(null, arg3);
      });
    },
    function (arg3, callback) {
      foo3(arg3, callback); // You can use `arg3` here again
    }], 
    function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
);
```

I couldn't say which one is better, in my code depending on the situation I use the first or second one.

It's been pointed out in the comments, but if you are getting to create something new I also recommend you to use Promises, code created through Async.js can get quite nasty in complex situations, especially waterfall and similar ones.

Comment: This solution works only if you want to pass a variable in the next task... What if I want the variable available everywhere ?

I know that the promises are a great way to avoid callback hell. But I found async.js quite powerful too in order to structure async code as well.

Comment: If you want the variable available everywhere your solution(external variable) is the only option left I think. Otherwise you'd have to pass the same variable along all the callbacks in the waterfall, becoming a bit verbose.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.